# Google chrome icon rendering

Tags: google-chrome

in my site I have problem in proper rendering of icons in Google Chrome as shown.

[image]

As you can see the right and bottom edge of image seems to be cut-off. But the same icons renders properly in all other browser including IE, FF, Safari.

Following is the screenshot of mozilla for the same.

[image]

Actually icons are of very big size around  almost 1000 X 1000px, and I'm showing that in 100 X 100px area. The problem is I can't scale down the images and I have to use these images only.

In chrome when I zoom-in or zoom-out my website, for a moment it renders correctly but again after some time is renders as shown above.

Any possible solution to this?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it myself by using `image-rendering` css property.